# put points from mysql in grid with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, grid

I have some points in my table in mysql .

this point is saved in column grid (number) the position in grid in html.

i do 2 loop for when i found the points the square be in color blue else i put the square in red but when i change the resolution of navigator the grid change and the point also and it position may be the grid is not responsive.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 930; i++) {
("#displaygrille").append('<div class="ui-block-a cell onCellClick" id="' + i + '">');
    $.each(res, function (k, v) {
        if(i == v.grille){

            console.log("Grille " + i + " = " + v.grille + " trouvée");
            $("#"+i).removeClass("onCellClick");
            $("#"+i).html('');
            $("#"+i).append('<div class="alveole-vide" ></div>');
            if( v.nb_cables > 0 ){

              $("#"+i).html('');
              $("#"+i).append('<div class="alveole-oqp"></div>');

            }
            if( v.reservation == "true" ){
                $("#"+i).html('');
                if( v.nb_cables > 0 ){

                $("#"+i).append('<div class="alveole-oqp"><div class="alveole-reza"></div></div>');

            }else{

                $("#"+i).append('<div class="alveole-vide"><div class="alveole-reza"></div></div>');

            }
        }
        if( (v.nb_cables == 0) && (v.reservation == "false")){

            $("#"+i).html('');
            $("#"+i).append('<div class="alveole-vide" ></div>');
        }
    }
});
$("#displaygrille").append('</div>');
}
```

i work with php mysql Jquery mobile.
any help plz

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this the question the point lost it position **but when i change the resolution of navigator the grid change and the point also**